# authentication-manager properties file Spring security

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I new to spring and I am unable to figure out whats the problem.

My **`spring-security.xml`**
`

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="classpath:users.properties"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>`
```

My **`users.properties`**

```
bob=bobspassword,ROLE_USER,enabled
```

My WebApp is not starting here the ***stacktrace***

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#15': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [users.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#15': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [users.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [users.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createInstance(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:98)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 133 more
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzeX8.png)

The guide I am following is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075170/how-to-move-username-passwords-out-of-spring-security-context-xml)

Comment: As the exception, it is caused by not found *users.properties*, Can you paste your project structure?

Comment: CAn you change this line from <user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="classpath:users.properties"/> to <user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="users.properties"/>

Comment: no luck @RadhakrishnaSharmaGorenta

Comment: ok. can you give the absolute path of the file and try once? like C:\workspace\users.properties

Comment: And also try "classpath:/users.properties"

Comment: Still same File not found. Can you tell me how to read from properties file ? @RadhakrishnaSharmaGorenta

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it there was a typo in my code.